# C# attribute formatting conventions

Tags: c#, formatting, attributes

Lately I've seen attribute tags formatted into two ways in C# (even in the official microsoft guide):

```
[foo]
public class bar {...}
```

and

```
[foo] public datatype bar;
```

Is there any advantage to where the tag is placed? Should the tag be placed in a certain position based on whether it is over a class or a datatype?

Comment: For c# compiler both are the same. Use whichever you think is more readable.

Comment: first one is easier to read and see the attribute easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's personal preference, it's not going to make any difference to the compiler, pick one and be consistent.

That said, I prefer the 1st format in both cases because it's possible to have multiple attributes on both classes and datatypes - and I find it easier to read spread out.
it would get messy quickly if you did that in-line.

take the following sample code for a class for example:

```
[Author("P. Ackerman", version = 1.1)]
[Author("R. Koch", version = 1.2)]
class SampleClass
{
    // P. Ackerman's code goes here... 
    // R. Koch's code goes here...
}
```

putting it inline just makes it unreadable.

Comment: btw do you prefer stacked attribute tags (like in your example) instead of `[foo(),bar(), version = num]`

Comment: yes, I do.

I personally find it easier to process things like this when they are visually distinct - where I'm looking for a separate attribute or just want less mental "noise" when considering a particular attribute or the class signature or datatype.

Then again, I often deal with things with multiple attributes that contain a lot of information. If your use case is different, where you know that you will have a few, short attributes at most, then putting them in-line may make sense if you prefer vertical compactness.